# Maven Non-resolvable import POM

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, maven

I'm using AWS ECS with EC2 instances and these instances are running java code. When trying to execute the code via maven I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:pom:1.11.106 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bom/1.11.106/aws-java-sdk-bom-1.11.106.pom @ line 16, column 19
```

I have seen a lot of posts mentioning that they needed to update settings.xml but in my case I do not have access to this as this code is being run in isolated docker container tasks. Is there anything I could add to the pom.xml file that would resolve this issues. Thanks.

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>aws.example.sqs</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-sqs-examples</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Amazon SQS Examples</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.106</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its complaining about **com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:pom:1.11.106**. This is a very OLD API and should not be used anymore.

It better practice to upgrade to [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2) and use a current POM that has:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
       <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
       <version>2.17.190</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Full POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>EC2J2Project</groupId>
    <artifactId>EC2J2Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.190</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ec2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering I tested this out on my local and it works - I think my EC2 instance has connection issues which I will debug.